# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER0_.NAME

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I work with small Spring boot app and I get the error `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER0_.NAME` during I compile. I have the same error before and now I reproduce it to the minimal amount of code. This is the project structure,

[image]

The error is triggered by the method `findAll()` from the controller,

```
    @Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/users")
    public String showAllUsers(Model model) {

        // triggered by this line
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
        return "list";
    }
}
```

The important part of the error stack is,

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_ from user user0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

......

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER0_.NAME in statement [select user0_.id as id1_1_, user0_.name as name2_1_ from user user0_]

.........

Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER0_.NAME
```

The entity class is provided,

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (getId() != user.getId()) return false;
        return getName().equals(user.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (int) (getId() ^ (getId() >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + getName().hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

The interfaces in the repository directory provided,

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

The user controller class is provided earlier. I can provide more info if required. My intention is will pass all the user values to the JSP page. I should mention, I don't have any user value now, the app will get the user info from a form and now it has nothing.

AS it asked from the comment, the services interface and classe are provided,

```
public interface UserService {

    List<User> findAll();

    User findById(Long idx);

    void save(User user);

    void delete(Long idx);
}
```

The service class implementation,

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return (List)userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(Long idx) {
        return userRepository.findOne(idx);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long idx) {
        userRepository.delete(idx);
    }
}
```

I use `HSQL` database and the application properties is provided,

```
server.port=8081
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.application.name=Bootstrap Spring Boot
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true 
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=.
security.basic.enabled=true
security.user.name=john
security.user.password=123

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:db/registration;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.username=testuser
spring.datasource.password=testpassword
server.error.path=/error
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false


# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the com.boot.registration.entity manager).
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.messages.basename=validation
```

`Update`

Appearantly, none of the operations of the service interface works and provide the same set of errors. For example, if I put the code like,

```
@GetMapping(value = "/users")
    public String showAllUsers(Model model) {

        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1L);
        user.setName("Berlin");

        userService.save(user);

//        model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
        return "list";
    }
```

I still have the same error `Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER0_.NAME`

What is the issue here?

Comment: Would you provide us the `UserServiceImpl` class?

Comment: Service is provided not much code there though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have excluded the `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration` from the `@SpringBootApplication` and this apparently solved the issue here.

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.boot"} , exclude = JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```